# React native flexbox: Distributing the items evenly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I have created this simple React Native Demo, which adds/removes Santa images to a Flexbox.

[Bunch of Santas](https://snack.expo.io/SkQbvbgVb)

When there are more than 3 Santas, the layout tends to shift to left. I am just wondering, what is the behavior and how to position the Santas in the middle of Flexbox, just like the time, when there are exactly three Santas.

Comment: Some runnable code?

Comment: @AftabKhan If you click on the "Bunch of Santas" link, you will get to see the code.

Comment: Some time ago, it was a broken link

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, if you don't want you first santa to start from center
You need to add `width` and balance it to the center using `margin:auto` on left and right.

https://snack.expo.io/rJzeAX4VZ

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking that Flexbox provides some kind of way to handle such scenarios. Fixing the width of the container does not feel 'flexboxish', but the solution is correct.